# Mathematical induction base case is not initial

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction

> Prove by induction that
>   $$1+2+3+\cdots+n= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$ for all integers greater than or equal to $2$

How can you solve this if the base case is not $1$? I thought it might be a strong induction case but strong induction also requires the initial case.  To solve this, should I just assume that the initial value $1$ is assumed?

Comment: If the base case is $17$, you prove by hand that the expressions on the left and right of the equality coincide Just add $1+2+\dots+17$, and also compute $17\times 18/2$ and then check whether you obtained the same answer.

Comment: The base case doesn't necessarily impose you to start with $1$. If you want to prove some property for say all $n\geqslant8$ then it suffices to check the base case for $n=8$ and then proceeding to the induction step. So for your particular case it suffices to check that the property holds for $n=2$ before moving forward.

Comment: So, I can start with 2 as the base case and add 2+1 here.  Great! Thank you.

Comment: You can prove it for all natural numbers and conclude it holds for all natural numbers greater than $2$.

Answer (score 0):

You can use induction on any infinite sequence of natural numbers (or integers, or any countably infinite sequence at all).

Basic induction says if S is a set of natural numbers and 0 is in S and (s + 1) is in S whenever s is in S then S = N, the whole set of natural numbers.

This is then applied to an inductive proof by letting S be the set of numbers for which P(s) is true, where P is a proposition based on the number s. So if P(0) is true then 0 is in S and if P(s+1) is true whenever P(s) is true then s+1 is in s whenever s is in S and S = N and P(n) is true for all n in N.

Is now T is some countably infinite sequence of  $t_0, t_1, ....$ let S be the set of numbers for which $P(t_s)$ is true. If $P(t_0)$ is true and $P(t_{s+1})$ is true whenever $P(t_s)$ is true, then S = N and P(t) is true for all of the sequence T.

In your case the sequence is simply the natural numbers starting from 2 instead of from 0.